# Wordpress/WooCommerce hooks not firing?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been through a lot of blogs and posts on SO before asking this question here.

I'm using WooCommerce plugin and was trying to get product data via action hooks to be passed to a 3rd party API.

I've tried various blocks of code but none of them gives me product information.

So, I'm trying to add/update/delete a product on WooCommerce with the following hooks placed in my child theme's `functions.php` file.

**Hook 1**

```
function on_all_status_transitions( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    echo '<script>console.log("old_status: ' . $old_status . '")</script>';
    echo '<script>console.log("new_status: ' . $new_status . '")</script>';
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'on_all_status_transitions', 10, 3 );
```

This only prints once when `$new_status` is `auto-draft` and then when I save it as a draft or publish or move it to trash, nothing happens.

**Hook 2**

```
function sync_on_product_save($product_Id){
    $product = wc_get_product($product_Id);
    echo '<script>console.log("Product Id: ' . $product_Id . '")</script>';    
    // Do what you need for 3rd party here...
}
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'sync_on_product_save', 10, 1);
```

This hook never gets triggered.

**Hook 3**

Same happens with the product update hook, never triggered.

`add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'sync_on_product_save', 10, 1);`

With all the reading that I have done, it seems that it is very obvious and should just work. So if someone can just point out what I might be doing wrong or something that I might be missing it would be great.

Also, I am aware that we can create webhooks in WooCommerce that can deliver the payload to a URL that we can specify. I would like to do this as a last option.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I'm running my Wordpress instance on localhost over wamp with https enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your hooks were firing all the time, while you are updating the products. You could see product Id when you dump the product id and kill the PHP execution.

```
function sync_on_product_save($product_Id){
    var_dump( $product_Id ); exit;
    echo '<script>console.log("Product Id: ' . $product_Id . '")</script>';    
    // Do what you need for 3rd party here...
}
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'sync_on_product_save', 10, 1);
```

The process will be like this: You hit the update product button, it will take you to post.php where your scripts will be added, soon it will redirect to your original product edit URL[http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=xx&action=edit]. This will remove your added scripts, which is why you are not able to see the scripts.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I was sure there was something of that sort happening but wasn't able to figure that out. Also, with @FahamShaikh answer, the advantage is that I do not have to kill the process and still get logs. That way it is better for debugging. But since your answer solved my problem I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you are trying to echo the script while the WP add-new/edit screens are in transition.

As @SushilAdhikari mentioned, your hooks are firing properly but your scripts are printed on **post.php** and it is then redirected to the edit screen after publish/update action.

To verify what data you are receiving when the hooks are triggered you need to log to a different file and check after the action has completed. I am sharing a small sample of what can be done to log the data.

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_product', 'custom_new_product_cb');
function custom_new_product_cb($id) {
    error_log('Data ID: '.print_r($id, true).PHP_EOL, 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/product-data.log");
}
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'custom_update_product_cb');
function custom_update_product_cb($id) {
    error_log('Updated Product ID: '.print_r($id, true).PHP_EOL, 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/product-data.log");
}
add_action('woocommerce_trash_product', 'custom_trash_product_cb');
function custom_trash_product_cb($id) {
    error_log('Trashed Product ID: '.print_r($id, true).PHP_EOL, 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/product-data.log");
}
```

If I am correct, the `$id` is passed as product reference so you can get product data from there and if you are trying to only add script to the screen then the approach should be different.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer mate. Since Sushil answered first and it did solve my problem, I'll will accept his answer but your answer is also correct and helpful, hence, I'm upvoting it.

Comment: @CodeWarrior Thanks for the upvote man. I am happy that your problem was solved. That matters more than the accepted answer. Have a good one mate!!